# How to automaticly send an email via outlook to the document controller in case of error

Tags: c#

I'm working on a script that shows a form with links to documents.
It's all working correctly but I would like to add a function that automaticly sends an email to the document controller that the selected document is not present.
The email content should contain text (string) with filename of the document that does not exist.

I have found several possibilities but I'm new to C# and I don't know were to start incorporating it in my current script. I want to use Microsoft Outlook for sending the emails.

I have created the following:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
#endregion
using static OpenDocument.Command;

using Form = System.Windows.Forms.Form;
using Application = Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application;
using View = Autodesk.Revit.DB.View;


namespace OpenDocument
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region Variables
        //Document links:
        string doc01 = @"C:\docs\3D ModelGuide.docx";
        string doc02 = @"C:\docs\3D Checklist.docx";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
    private void btnModelguide3D_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFile(doc01);
    }
    private void btnChecklist3D_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFile(doc02);
    }

    void openFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName) == true)
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
        }
        else
        {
           TaskDialog.Show("Info", notFoundError(fileName));
        }
    }

string notFoundError(string fileName)
        {
           string info = "The requested file/folder" + "\n" + fileName + "\n" + "does not exist!"
           return info;
        }
```

Comment: would it not be better to use an SMTP server to send the mail? Then your application is not dependent on Office.

Comment: We all have Microsoft Outlook here in the company. So I want to use that.
I have found several scripts that require hardcode passwords... but I don't want that. I want to use the active Outlook session. Is that even possible?

Comment: I think it might be possible. But Outlook is an email program that uses a server to send email. The program you write can just use the server.

Comment: If you all use Outlook then you all use Exchange. So just send the mail via Exchange's SMTP server directly. More lightweight, easier to implement, uses standard protocols etc etc.

Comment: @RichardHousham - but using that server also requiers coding the password correct?

Comment: "that server also requiers coding the password"...not necessarily. Depends how it's configured. But you may be able to authenticate as the user who is running the app - if they are already able to send mail via Outlook (which connects to Exchange) then they should be authorised to send mail generally.

Comment: Yeah, I use an AppPool account that can be configured. Entering the password into a config file is also a way to go. So options..